# C++ exception specification for iostream operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, noexcept

It is not specified if call to [ostream operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) can fail or throw any exception and I have never encounter this.

1. Is there a case where [ostream operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) could fail ?
2. If no, why standard does not put [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier to these overloads ?
3. Is the following overload valid ? good practice ? commonly used ?
4. Same question for [istream operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) ?

```cpp
struct MyClass {
    int data;
    // I/O operators with noexcept specifier
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, MyClass &obj) noexcept;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MyClass &obj) noexcept;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason none of the `operator >>` and `operator <<` are marked as `noexcept` is because of [`std::basic_ios::exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).  This member function is present in all objects that inherit from `std::basic_ios` and allows you to configure the stream to throw exceptions for certain failure modes.  If the operators were `noexcept` then you could not use them with a stream that has exceptions set.

Comment: This feels like it only answers the 2nd question adequately. Then again, an OP shouldn't put a lot of questions in the same question, so there's that.

Comment: @Chipster To me, *If the operators were noexcept then you could not use them with a stream that has exceptions set* covers all of the questions.  UB is a good reason not to do something.

Comment: It doesn't answer question 1, I don't think. The OP seems to want an example. But I suppose that's just me.

Comment: @Chipster Do I really need to show a stream getting the exception set to show how an exception can be thrown when it hit an error?

Comment: I guess not. Would be nice though. You have a point, though, so I'll upvote anyway.

Comment: I think ```std::basic_ios::exceptions``` answers questions 1, 2 & 4. Indeed, as I understand, standard iostream operators can throw in file read/write context. Nevertheless, what prevents the user to handle exceptions in operator overload ? --> question 3 is still accurate.

Comment: @Baptistou You could handle exceptions in your own type but if you can't overload the operators for built in types so there is no way to catch from inside the function for those types, hence those operators being not noexcept.  The whole purpose of enabling exceptions is you want them to fire and surface to your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. It can fail and you can either use return values for knowing the result or enable exceptions with std::ostream::exceptions method.

The example is for std::iostream.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    std::cout.exceptions ( std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit );

    try {

        // operations with the stream ...
    
    } catch (const std::ios::failure & ex) {

    }
 
}
```

2. They generally can.
3. It is valid, but you must guarantee exceptions are not thrown out of them in fact. If an exception is attempted to be thrown out from the methods you provided, std::terminate will be called, since it is what happens for functions declared with **noexcept** when an exception is leaving them.
4. The same is for std::istream.